# Submit text to same HTML page

Tags: java, model-view-controller, submit, thymeleaf

I have made a text field and a submit button in my view in the admin page, and i want to do so the text i submit is shown below my textbox on the same page.

This is my controller for getting to the adminPage:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/adminPage", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String adminPage(Model model) {

return "adminPage";
}
```

this is what i have for my adminPage:

```
<form th:action="@{/adminPage}" method="post">
    <textarea rows="4" cols="50">
</textarea>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" 
value="Submit Text"/>

</form>
```

I'm still very new at controllers and MVC in general, and i find it hard to use my knowledge in Java because Controllers doesn't look like any Java i've used before, so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: use javascript for that. you don't need to submit anything to the server since it is all client side.

Comment: we havn't learned any javascript at school, i feel lost..

Comment: yeah but javascript is not the answer if he wants to submit to a server :) which is sometimes the case - if he decides to store that info and not just display it

Comment: I'm not familiar with MVC myself, but I would presume that you need to figure out how to get the data from your html client and put it into the `model`, which is available to your controller. I'd start answering this question myself by learning about that `Model` object and how MVC is managing its linkage between the client and server

Answer (score 0):

ok then, no Javascript. First, textarea needs a name attribute `name="inputText"`.

That name will be used in the model object when your server method receives the request:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/adminPage", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String adminPage(@RequestParam("inputText") String input, Model model) {
    //Do stuff
    model.addAttribute("theText", input); //add the text which can be accessed on "adminPage"
    return "adminPage";
}
```

then you can add a `<div>` in "adminPage.jsp" and append your text there, like:

```
<div>${theText}</div>
```

Comment: Ah great solution! I still need an identifier for input though, String is fine i guess.

Comment: yeah sorry fixed that. I was just typing free hand :)

Answer (score 0):

If, I have understood your problem correctly than here is the workaround that will do the job.

When user visits `/adinPage` from browser than `input_data` variable will be `null` and the if condition won't be executed.
The JSP page will be returned with second `textarea` as blank.

You have to use `JSP` because `HTML` pages can't be altered.

**Controller.java**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/adminPage", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String adminPage(@RequestParam(value = "input_data", required = false) String input_data,Model model) 
{
     if(input_data!=null)
         model.addAttribute("output_data",input_data);

     return "adminPage";
}
```

**adminPage.jsp**

```
<form th:action="@{/adminPage}" method="post">

       <textarea id="input_data" rows="4" cols="50">
       </textarea>

       <textarea rows="4" cols="50">
       ${output_data}
       </textarea>

       <input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" 
       value="Submit Text"/>

</form>
```

When the user submits the form, the if condition will be executed and the returned view will contain the previously input data in second `textarea`

I haven't tested the code so, it might contain some syntax errors.